# Stop an Increment

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

I have the Y axis increasing very few frames with the following line:

```
Bullets.center = CGPointMake(Airplane.center.x, Airplane.center.y + Y);
```

How can I stop increasing Y when an if statement is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I'd say "don't add Y if the statement is true", but I may be misunderstanding your question, it seems quite simple.  A [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in the CGPointMake will take care of it:

```
Bullets.center
    = CGPointMake(Airplane.center.x, Airplane.center.y + (CONDITION ? 0 : Y));
```